# Can MySQL do a calculation using a field that is already a calculated one with SUM()?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a field in a mySQL query that's the sum of other fields. Can that result be inside another calculation as well?

I want to sum all fields and that field be rested from other field, like this:

```
    SUM(partialPayments) AS totalPaid,
    SUM(totalAmount - totalPaid) AS balance
```

`partialPayments` and `totalAmount` are fields, but `totalPaid` is the created field when I sum up partial values. Is there a way to achieve that?

### The query that I'm using is this one:

```
SELECT      usuarios.userNombres, usuarios.docVerificada, 
            cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.cursoPrecio, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol,
            SUM(pagos.pagoMonto) AS total,
            SUM(cursos.cursoPrecio - pagos.pagoMonto) AS saldo

FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN pagos
ON usuarios.userID = pagos.userID

LEFT JOIN cursos
ON pagos.cursoID = cursos.cursoID

LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
ON usuarios.userID = rolesUsuarios.userID

WHERE pagos.estadoPago = 1
AND cursos.cursoID = 15

GROUP BY usuarios.userID, pagos.cursoID
```

The result I get is this one:

[image]

The first row shows under "total" it shows "55" which is actually the sum of two partials (32 + 23). The last column, "saldo", should calculate 7000 - 55 = 6945. Instead, it shows 13945.
The same issue with the third row.

Comment: why not just do `SUM(partialPayments) AS totalPaid,
SUM(totalAmount - partialPayments) AS balance` .... Note that I changed the Amount column name from what I thought of as a typo from you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: Yeah if this is put in a [fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464)  <----- my silly self answer

Comment: `SUM(totalAmount) - SUM(partialPayments) AS balance`